# store product and category in one table is good or else we can use seperate table for category and product?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I am totally confused to store category and product data stored in the same table in hierarchical relation/Parent-child relation use in a table or if we create two separate table for category and product table?

[image]

in above table, i used the same table for storing category and product with parentId and childId, If we use like this then what benefits? Or we use a separate table for category and product and why? Please anyone help me

Comment: This needs to be cleaned up. The question indicated in the title is different from the question in the first paragraph. And the data in the attachment indicates yet another question.

Comment: How many levels can the hierarchy go. If it is only one deep, I’d have a seperate table called category. Make it a lot easier to query

Comment: Yea @AbBennett i need reason what are different reason in both table to store data like this?

Comment: If your asking why to store data in two tables, it’s just a nicer design, easier to query. The way you have it though is ok though, you will just be joining the table to itself a lot, and a left join at that. Downside is they are stuck having the same attributes. It is really only logiclal to have a hierarchy like that for things that are the same such as employees having a link to another employee as their manager etc, and whereby the number of levels is infinite. If you wish to create a fk I think you will need a zero entry record that points to itself, I honestly would have two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on if the relationship between store and product categories are one to many or many to many and if a single category can only belong to one category tree.

If the relationship is one to many, and a category can only belong to one tree, then you'll be able to use a single table, with a foreign key referencing the same table.

Otherwise, you'll likely be looking 2 or 3 tables. At a minimum you'll need one table for your categories, and then another for you relationship (what's known as a composite key table).

Also, if Product categories and Store Categories are inherently different (hold different data) then you should be using separate tables for them anyway.